# Wordpress - Ignore or Temporarily Disable Plugin on Menu Save

Tags: php, wordpress, cloudflare

I have a site with a massive menu.  Please understand, it is the clients requirements that the menu be as big as it is, so no, it cannot be done any other way.

The site is run through Cloudflare, so we have the Cloudflare plugin installed to purge the cache when updates happen.

What I've found, is that saving the menu in admin, causes a 502 error because the save script timesout.   We have found that the culprit is the Cloudflare plugin performing Curl requests for the purges, a great many times due to the size of the menu.

What I am trying to do is disable the plugin when the menu saves, so I have create a Must Use plugin with the proceeding code to accomplish this... however, it does not appear to be working and the plugin's purge Curl processes are still firing off.

**NOTE:** php input max, script timeout, memory limits have all been highly increased: 5000, 5Minutes, 1024M respectivly.  Cloudflare has a strict timeout period so, that actually times out before the script does... the only reason I know what happens is because it's tested and logged in a staging area.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Disable Plugins in Admin pages
Plugin URI: http://www.example.com
Description: Disable plugins in wordpress admin pages
Author: Kevin Pirnie
Version: 0.0.1
*/

// wait until the plugins are active
add_filter( 'option_active_plugins', function( $_opt, $_opt_name ) {

    // plugins to remove
    $_to_remove = array(
        'cloudflare/cloudflare.php',
    );

    // hold our new options
    $_new_opts = $_opt;

    // remove the plugin from the array
    foreach ( $_opt as $_k => $_v ) {
        if ( in_array( $_v, $_to_remove ) ) {
            unset( $_new_opts[$_k] );
        }
    }

    // we only need to do this on these pages
    if( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == '/wp-admin/nav-menus.php' ) {
        $_opt = $_new_opts;
    }

    // return the array
    return $_opt;

}, 999, 2 );
```

How can I fix this so the plugin does NOT run when the menu saves?

Comment: A question: Is it possible to increase the server's max_execution_time limit? If you prevent the Cloudflare cache from being flushed maybe the changes in the menu won't be reflected in the site.

Comment: added a **note** to the question.   In short- been there done that

Comment: forgot to add...  not concerned about menu changes and cache purging.  changes to it are less frequent than content changes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really test since I don't have a site behind Cloudflare now, but give it a try to this:

```
<?php

// Use the filter provided by Clodflare's plugin and return an empty array for the urls
// check wp-content/plugins/cloudflare/src/WordPress/Hooks.php line 155 to see what happens behind this
add_filter('cloudflare_purge_by_url', function($urls, $postId) {
    global $pagenow;

    //Act only if the current screen is the Admin Menu
    if ("nav-menus.php" === $pagenow) {
        $urls = [];
    }

    return $urls;
});
```

Cloudflare's plugin provides that filter to modify the url's array before purging the cache.

Good luck!